# Python | How interpolate two measurements such that the x-values are the same

Tags: python, interpolation

I have two measurements consisting of x and y value pairs. I want to calculate the difference between these two series. The problem is that I cannot simply calculate the difference between these two measurements because they are sampled differently in the x values.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y1 = np.array([1, 4, 9, 16, 25])
x2 = np.array([1.5, 2.5, 3.3, 4.2, 5.1])
y2 = np.array([1.3, 2.5, 3.3, 4.2, 5.1])
df = np.array([x1, y1, x2, y2])
df = pd.DataFrame(df.T, columns=['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2'])
df.head()

plt.plot(df.x1.values, df.y1.values, df.x2.values, df.y2.values)
```

I would like to assign a new variable x = np.linspace(0, 5, 100, endpoint=True) and then determine new y1_new and y2_new by interpolating the y1 and y2 values on the values of x.

I have looked at pandas.resample() but that seems to be working with timestamps. Maybe 'scipy.interpolate' could help but I am not sure about the capabilities. In principle, I know how to program this by hand in python, but I am sure that there is already a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of using the `scipy.interpolate` would be:

```py
import scipy.interpolate as interp
import numpy as np
x1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y1 = np.array([1, 4, 9, 16, 25])
new_x1 = np.linspace(0, 5, 100, endpoint=True)
interpolated_1 = interp.interp1d(x1, y1, fill_value="extrapolate")
new_y1 = interpolated_1(new_x1)
new_y1
```

All the other methods follow the same signature, more or less, as you can see in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html). Which one to use, depends on the underlying data you have, for example, the first looks like a quadratic and the second the identity.